# Edit text validation

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am new to android..
I want to add edit text validation, like user enter mobile number.  If number is less than 10 digits it will show in red color and if it is right it will show blue color..

How to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Set the `inputtype` of `edittext` to `number` and check it like this.

```
if(editText.getText().length() < 10) {
  ..Invalid Number
  editText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
} else {
   editText.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
   Valid Number
}
```

Comment: it will check only number is valid or not.. i want to add colour with that.. valid color than blue if not than red

Comment: @SahilPatel Make this answer accept if this solve your problem..

Answer (score 0):

You should follow best practices of android....

```
if (myEditText.getText().toString().trim().length() < 10) {
    myEditText.setError("Please entre 10 digits");     
}
```